# Check that the app runs for the first time

Tags: c++, qt, mobile, qml, qtquick2

I'm new to qt mobile development and I have a rather dumb question.
How would I check whether a user runs the app for the first time (both Android and iOS)?

EDIT:

The reason I need this check is that I have an intro SwipeView for the first-timers and after it's read once it should always open the main app screen.

I've tried the way @TrebledJ suggested and it seems to work alright, Or is this stupid to do that in main.cpp?

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSettings>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QSettings settings;
QVariant firstRun = settings.value("first-run");

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QUrl startingScreen(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

if(!firstRun.isValid())
    settings.setValue("first-run", true);
else
    startingScreen.setUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/start.qml"));

engine.load(startingScreen);
if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;

return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The first time it's run, there may be no settings set?

Comment: You must create or modify a disk file or some other resource that is persistent. It might also be that you can rely on the file creation and last file access date/time.

Comment: One way would be to iterate currently running processes on the system and check if any of them are an instance of your application, if it is, exit.

Comment: @AlienTed Do you have [mcve]s of `main.qml` and `start.qml` that could be shared with us, by any chance?

Comment: @TrebledJ Not yet. I'm trying qt only for a couple of hours. Still figuring out how everithing works here. I'll share when I have something that works, to a minimum extent at least. Anyways, thanks a lot for the help. Not too much info on mobile development with qt.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`QSettings`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#value) to check for a set value.

```
QSettings settings;
QVariant val = settings.value("first-time");
if (!val.isValid()) {
    // ... first run
    settings.setValue("first-time", false);  // set a value so that the value is valid on the next run    
} else {
    // ... not first run
}
```

In QML, there is the [`Settings`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html) QML Type.

```
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

Settings {
    id: settings
    property bool isFirstTime: true
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    if (settings.isFirstTime) {
        // ... first run
        settings.isFirstTime = false;
    } else {
        // ... not first run
    }
}
```

However, according to documentation:

> **Note**: This type is made available by importing the **Qt.labs.settings** module. Types in the Qt.labs module are not guaranteed to remain compatible in future versions.

In consideration of the non-guarantee, Felgo/V-Play's API has a [`Storage`](https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-storage/) QML Type which can also perform the check in QML. (The first example in their documentation implements this.)

Comment: We can still remove the settings to make your check wrong... (Even if I think it is what OP wants).

Comment: @Jarod42 How so? I'm curious.

Comment: Depend of platform, IIRC, `QSettings` are saved in registry on Windows.

Comment: @Jarod42 The [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)? It... looks safe and persistent to me. I'm still unsure how my check is wrong.

Comment: Yes, even if persistent. user can modify it **manually**, and so invalidating your check. (You might see it as cheating so ;-) )

Comment: Haha, how'd one work around that? Store it on the web maybe? :P

Comment: sometimes, you'd want to clear that flag. i.e Android app "clear data" option clears all `Settings` and next time it runs, it runs as a first-time. so "manual" reset, in this case, is a need.